# Mixing different disks in RAID or ZFS

Tags: partitioning, raid, zfs

I want to create a RAID (actually a zfs raidz) with disks from different manufactures. The disks will be roughly the same, e.g., SATA, 3 TB, 7200 rpm.

Since the disks will probably have small differences in size (several MB probably) the RAID creation will fail if not all partitions are the same size. I am willing to waste some MB (or even GB) at the end of each disk.

The question is: how big should I size my zfs partition on each disk?

Looking at the current disks is not enough, since a disk migh fail and the replacement might be different.

So, which safe margin is enough? Are all 3 TB (or x TB) disks out there guaranteed to have at least x Byte of size? Is it safe to assume that a disk labeld with **x TB** provides at least **x * 1000^4 Byte** of storage?

I know about the performance inpact of mixing different drives. Since the project is more about storing data the performance of the weakest disk is more than enough.

Comment: ZFS might complain but it *will* make it work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1220055/whole-harddisk-vs-smaller-partition-for-zfs-vdev/1225838#1225838).

All manufacturers specify their capacity in the spec sheets and also (sometimes) on the disk themselves. If they would not have that, you could return the disk to the vendor because it does not have its promised quality. The problem is the other way round, most disks exceed that number, because of exactly that fact (and also because sectors do not perfectly align to round numbers), so you could have some "generous" disks at start and your array would be too big for more "normal" disks later on. This is the reason for said advice.

Additionally, some sectors might become unreadable without the whole drive dying, so it might be cheaper to keep using the slightly smaller drive (although I have experienced this only with flash media yet).

Comment: partitioning the disks seams reasonable. Is there an overview on how much more the manufacturers give the disks? or if any one goes below the advertised size?